# CSS not appearing on the browser

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to set up my page and style it using CSS, and I've linked my CSS to my code. However, nothing I do on my style sheet is appearing on my browser.

I've looked at other questions and seen their solutions and nothing is wrong as far as I can tell.

This is my header code:

```
<?php
    require_once 'includes/database.php';
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home<a></li>
                <li><a href="login.php">Login<a></li>
                <li><a href="register.php">Register<a></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
    </header>
```

This is my CSS:

```
*{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header{
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}
```

This is my index code (I doubt you'd need this but putting this in just in case):

```
<?php
    require_once 'includes/header.php';
    ?>


HOME

<?php

    require_once 'includes/footer.php';
    
?>
```

screenshot of browser + network tab:

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kCrW.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot on the browser developer tool > Network tab? Wanna check if the browser actually download the css

Comment: @Mr.Brickowski I've added it! Hope that helps

Comment: Where is this `style.css` file? Is it in the same folder as the `index.php` page or is it in the `includes` folder?

Comment: @Robson it's in the same folder as index.php

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? What **exactly** do you mean by "CSS not appearing in browser"?

Comment: @NicoHaase Hi! The question was answered a few days ago. In terms of what I meant by the CSS not appearing, the webpage was working as if no CSS was applied to it. I attached a screenshot.

Comment: If this question was answered a few days ago, why is there no accepted answer?

Comment: It was answered in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file should be outside of the includes folder.

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine. I can see the styles. [image]

Check your folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `href="stye.css"` with `href="/stye.css"`. Additionally, check that the case of letters is correct, also taking into account the `.css` extension.

It is also a good practice for SEO to use full paths for all links. It's best to do it this way:

```
define('HOST_NAME',(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? 'https' : 'http') . '://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

<link href="<?php echo HOST_NAME;?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

You can also use relative paths to include file:

```
<?php require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/header.php';?>
```

Answer (score -1):

there is a bug on your **ul** tag Also in CSS when you want a style to cater for the whole page you can use

```css
*{
/*Your Syle*/
}
/*rather than*/
html{
/*Your style*/
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! The CSS still doesn't affect the HTML though- even after applying your changes.